# Can't add a watched tag without the mouse

Tags: bug, accessibility, homepage, tag-watching

<sub>Next installment in the keyboard accessibility series ;)</sub>

As I've mentioned previously, keyboard accessibility is an important part of making sure that your site is accessible.

Watched tags fail that test.

If you don't have any watched tags at all, then there's no way to add one from the watched tags box on the front page. <kbd>tab</kbd> goes from the last featured Meta post to "Hot Network Questions".

If you have watched tags, you can add a tag by <kbd>tab</kbd>bing over to "edit". From there, you can add a tag... but there's no way to delete one. <kbd>tab</kbd> goes from one tag to the next, skipping over the "x" to remove one.

Comment: It's not convenient, but you can watch/ignore a tag from the page showing all questions tagged with it (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)).